# play mp3 song using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

I am developing an online listen music website, on that I want to play song based on the user selection from gridview.right now I am using flash object for playing mp3 and video file this is running fine but its static path.how I can dynamically pass file URL of selected song on flash object.

waiting for your reply.

Comment: does it have to be flash? Because there are media player controls available for asp.net that could fit your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello friends i have got the answer for dynamically play the song.here is my code for this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Play Now"))
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = gridCalls.Rows[index];
        string songname = row.Cells[5].Text; // second column in the sql server database
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("<object width='300px' height='300px'>");
        str.Append("<param name='autostart' value='true'>");
        str.Append("<param name='src' value='songs/" + songname + "'>");
        str.Append("<param name='autoplay' value='true'>");
        str.Append("<param name='controller' value='true'>");
        str.Append("<embed width='300px' height='300px' src='songs/" + songname + "' controller='true' autoplay='true' autostart='True' type='audio/wav' />");
        str.Append("</object>");

        LoadPlayer.Text = str.ToString();//here loadplayer is label control
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using flashvars (requires reloading the page/SWF)

The easiest way would be to pass in the URL as a flashvar, e.g. via the querystring of the SWF file in your object/embed tag:

```
MyPlayer.swf?url=/path/to/song.mp3
```

The `/path/to/song.mp3` can of course be printed by some server-side logic.

In Flash, you can then access the value of this variable using the `LoaderInfo` instance of the root:

```
var url : String = root.loaderInfo.parameters['url'];
```

If you want to provide a default for when no flashvar is specified, which is great for dev purposes especially, you can do this by using the `||` operator.

```
var url : String = root.loaderInfo.parameters['url'] || 'default.mp3';
```

This will use the specified URL if such exists, or else fall back to use default.mp3.

## Using ExternalInterface & Javascript

If you don't want to reload the page, set up a javascript interface to your Flash player using ExternalInterface, e.g. like so:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.addCallback('playUrl', playUrl);
}

function playUrl(url : String) : void {
    // TODO: Add playback code here, e.g. using new Sound(url);
}
```

Then, from Javascript, you can do this:

```
var swf = document.getElementById('idOfSwfEmbed');
swf.playUrl('http://example.com/path/to/song.mp3');
```

This will invoke the ActionScript method `playUrl()` using the javascript API that was set up by `ExternalInterface.addCallback()`.

I don't know .NET, so you'll need to figure out yourself how to invoke the `playUrl()` javascript method when a song is selected in your GridView.

Comment: flash object page is not different,but this object is available on the same page on gridvewi available.

Comment: @mayur: I'm not sure I understand you. Are you saying that you don't want to reload the page? If that's the case, then have a look at ExternalInterface. If you are reloading the page (or navigating to a separate page to play the song) then the above solution will work fine.

Comment: richardolsson,i dont want to postback the page and also dont want it to navigate on another page

Comment: mayur: I have updated my answer to provide an ExternalInterface-based solution, which will allow you to communicate with the Flash music player without reloading the page/SWF.

Comment: Of course you can use this even if your server-side solution is built using .NET. The client code is still just regular HTML, Javascript and CSS, regardless of whether it was rendered by a .NET back-end.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `<object />` tag to add the *.swf to the page:

Add following to the tag:

```
<object ...>
    <param name="flashvars" value="path=<%# YOUR_PATH; %>">
</object>
```

And then inside the SWF:

```
var path:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.path;
```